# How to pass array contents back and forth between managed (C#) and unmanaged (C++) code

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, marshalling

I'm trying to pass an array of floats from C# to a C++ dll which will do some work on that array and then pass back an answer in the form of an array of float (not necessarily of the same length).

I have code that will pass the array, modify it and then return it, but the values in the array are not as expected though the array appears otherwise well formed...
The example below takes an array of floats, passes it to C++. In C++ a value of 2 is added to every element of the array in order to simulate the work done and the result is returned to C# using a callback.
A different set of values is returned everytime.
A typical set of returned values is:-
81.58881, 2, 75.75787, 4

Any thoughts would be gratefully recieved..
Cheers
Graham

**C#**

```
public delegate void CallBack1(IntPtr param, int len);
[DllImport("TestDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void testCPlusSide(CallBack1 cb, IntPtr arr, int len);

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float[] dataIn = new float[] { 0, 0.5f, 7.79f, 46 };
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(dataIn);

    CallBack1 testCB = new CallBack1(TestCallBack);

    testCPlusSide(testCB, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch), dataIn.Length);

    gch.Free();
}

void TestCallBack(IntPtr param, int len)
{
    float[] vals = new float[len];
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(param);
    Marshal.Copy(param, vals, 0, len);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (float item in vals)
    {
        sb.Append(item.ToString() + "\n");
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

**C++**

```
typedef void(__stdcall * CallBack1)(float * arr, int len);
__declspec(dllexport) void testCPlusSide(CallBack1 cb, float* arr, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        arr[i] += 2;
    }
    cb(arr, len);
}
```

**UPDATE**
I added a temporary `float` to read the contents of the array on the C++ side and I have discovered that the contents of the array C++ side bear no relationship to the values passed - I have no idea why....

Comment: Might be worth adding some diagnostic prints in the c++. Just to see what the array had before and after on that side of the boundary.

Comment: If you are developing on Windows, have you tried debugging this with Visual Studio and stepping into the C++ from the C#?

Comment: Yes - to both the debugging and the diagnositic ouput - that was what prompted the update.
I also changed the C# side dllimport definition to:-
public static extern void testCPlusSide(CallBack1 cb, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] float[] x, int len);
which passed the data correctly, but gave a System.ExecutionEngineException error at the point when the callback was called in C++

Comment: Appraently this is an obsolete error message indicating an unspecified fatal error in the runtime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get things working.
I changed the GCHandle.Alloc method so it made a Pinned Object pointer and everything worked.
I also removed an unnecessary GCHandle call in the TestCallBackFunction
The full changed code is:-

**C#**

```
public delegate void CallBack1(IntPtr param, int len);
[DllImport("TestDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]  

public static extern void testCPlusSide(CallBack1 cb, IntPtr arr, int len);
    
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float[] dataIn = new float[] { 0, 0.5f, 7.79f, 46 };
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(dataIn,GCHandleType.Pinned);

    CallBack1 testCB = new CallBack1(TestCallBack);

    testCPlusSide(testCB, gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), dataIn.Length);
    
    gch.Free();
}
    
void TestCallBack(IntPtr param, int len)
{
    float[] vals = new float[len];
    Marshal.Copy(param, vals, 0, len);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (float item in vals)
    {
        sb.Append(item.ToString() + "\n");
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

**C++**

```
typedef void(__stdcall * CallBack1)(float * arr, int len);

__declspec(dllexport) void testCPlusSide(CallBack1 cb, float* arr, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        arr[i] += 2;
    }
    cb(arr, len);
}
```

Thanks to Carlos and rhughes for your help
Cheers
Graham

Comment: That just is not necessary, the pinvoke marshaller already ensures that an array is pinned while the native code is running.  Declaring the parameter as `float[]` is all that's required.  If the native code stores the pointer and the callback occurs later, after testCPlusSide() completes, then you have the kind of problem that requires keeping the array object alive and pinned.  Something you always want to avoid, pinning is painful to the GC.  The longer it stays pinned, the worse it gets.

Comment: Hi Hans - sorry declaring which parameter as float?  In an above comment I explored declaring:-  
public static extern void testCPlusSide(CallBack1 cb, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] float[] x, int len); 

This lead to an error in the unmanaged code when the callback was used - to be fair it was a Debugger error.
Please can you expand on what you are saying?